# JQuery scrollTop function goes to correct position but then jumps back to top of page

Tags: jquery, scroll, click, scrolltop

I used the JQuery function `scrollTop` on a list of contact numbers in a click function for each letter.  It scrolls to where it is supposed to but then scrolls back to the top immediately.

Here is a sample of the function in the code:

```
$('.a').click(function(){
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#A').position().top}, 'slow');
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle I made for it:
http://jsfiddle.net/CR47/MdtSE/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're adding this to an anchor tag, you normally need to add a `preventDefault()` or `return false;` to cancel the navigation event.

So:

```
$('.a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#A').position().top}, 'slow');
});
```

or

```
$('.a').on('click', function(e){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#A').position().top}, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

I also updated your sample to use the recommended syntax from jQuery 1.8+.

**EDIT:** As @Karl-Andre Gagnon points out:

> return false work because it prevent the event from bubbling since
>   preventDefault prevent the default action of the element. Since a
>   click on a span has no default action, it does nothing!

So the first example will only really work if you're using something like

`<a href="#" class="a">Back to top</a>`

Comment: Ah! I had tried the e.preventDefault(); but that didn't work, the return false; did though!  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah return false work because it prevent the event from bubbling since preventDefault prevent the default action of the element. Since a click on a span has no default action, it does nothing!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I thought as much when the OP made his comment above. Thanks! I'll expand the answer a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You writted the "a" `span` like that :

```
<span class="a">A</spam>
```

Due to this typo, it is not closed. That's causing every click (on any letter) to be a click on the "a" after bubbling.

Just change the "m" for a "n" and everything work fine.

Those damn typos, messing up the entire code :)